# Can CustomValidators be used to prevent data entry into textboxes?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have added the code below into my Angular component:

```
NumberValidator(event,element) {
    if (this.onlyNumberKey(event) == false)
      return false;
    if (this.maxLength(event) == false)
      return false;
    else
      return true;

  }

  maxLength(event) {
    var test = event.target.value;
    if (event.target.value.length + 1 > 2)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }

  onlyNumberKey(event) {
    let charCode = (event.query) ? event.query : event.keyCode;
    console.log(charCode);
    if (charCode > 31
      && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
      return false;

    return true;
  }
```

and my html:

```
<input type="text" (keypress)="firstNameValidator($event, this)" formControlName="firstName" required>
```

Is there a more elegant way to do this using Angular Reactive forms as it seems like a bit of a hack to me.  I have looked into CustomValidators, however, they only appear to tell you if there is a validation error or not i.e. they do not appear to stop data entry into text boxes if a validation error occurs.

Comment: Why not change the input type to "number"?

Comment: @Mark S, the maxLength function would still be needed with a number.  Or would it?

Comment: There are lots of [validators](https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators) that are built into Angular that can be individually or in combination when it comes to Reactive Forms. These are not working for you?

Comment: R. Richard's, from what I see they dont allow you to stop data entry if an error is occurred - they only appear to warn you if a data entry error occurs and prevent submission? I could be wrong though

Comment: @w0051977 With an input type of number, you can specify the "max" and "min" values allowed in that field

Comment: @Mark S, it does not prevent you from entering 101 into a number field with a max value of 100 I e. You are allowed to enter 101, but see a warning preventing submission.

Comment: I wouldn't prevent invalid input entirely. It could lead to poor UX. Imagine trying to type a value of 101 but the input box prevents the last 1 from being entered, because the max value is 100. Now you've only entered 10 in the box, and there's nothing telling you why the last 1 is being completely ignored.

Comment: I think one way to solve it(which is still a hack) would be to use a directive and there keep track of form control's value and validity. And if the form control turns out to be invalid, show the previous valid value to the user.

Comment: @AndreiGătej Thanks for an idea!

Answer (score 1):

The best way for you to achieve this would be to make a custom directive.

Custom Directives can listen into any event that you have defined, ex, keyup/keydown using HostListener.

You can define your validation in this directive and use it application wide to the text fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute [`Directive`](https://angular.io/guide/attribute-directives) available in Angular, which will listen for `keydown` event of an input and with the help of `EventEmitter`:

HTML Code:

```
Enter numbers:
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="value" onlyNumbersWithMax (onMaxValueReached)='onMaxValueReached_Client($event)'/>
<br/>
<div *ngIf="warningMessage">{{warningMessage}}</div>
```

Component.TS code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  warningMessage : any = "";

  onMaxValueReached_Client(message) {
    this.warningMessage = message;
  }
}
```

Directive.TS Code:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "input[onlyNumbersWithMax]"
})

export class NumberDirective {
  @Output() onMaxValueReached = new EventEmitter();
  maxValue: number = 2; // Set the max value here for input values

  constructor(private _el: ElementRef) { }

  @HostListener("keydown", ["$event"]) onInputChange(event) {
    const initalValue = this._el.nativeElement.value; // Get the initial value
    this.onMaxValueReached.emit(undefined);  // Reset the error
    let charCode = event.query ? event.query : event.keyCode;
    if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57) &&
      this._el.nativeElement.value == ""
    ) {
      // This code block is just a work around to reset the character or invalid value as we are using keydown event so the flow of control is just moving before setting empty value
      var that = this;
      setTimeout(function () {
        that._el.nativeElement.value = "";
      }, 10);
      event.stopPropagation();
    } else {
      if (initalValue.length >= this.maxValue && charCode != 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.onMaxValueReached.emit(
          "The max value for an input is " + this.maxValue
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[`Here is a working demo`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-numbers-only-directive-and-max-validation)

Comment: Sorry, this just doesn't work.  I have tried your code in Visual Studio 2017 and it does not allow me to enter anything into the textbox.

Comment: @w0051977 you check log the details of the value n check where it going wrong

Comment: @w0051977 or you can share the stackblitz where i can reproduce an issue

Comment: Your code only restricts the first character to a number - the second character can be anything.  For example, it is possible to enter: 1a, 2b, 5f etc.

Comment: It appears if you add a breakpoint (and it is reached) in any part of the code, then nothing appears (even numbers) in the textbox.  If no breakpoint is reached, then my code works in the same way as your code.

Comment: Are you able to answer the question in my comment above about breakpoints before I mark the answer as accepted? Thanks.

Comment: @w0051977 looks strange! Might be related to VS 2017? Or something else. can't guess without any code example.

Comment: I have asked another question about it here and provided a code sample if you could take a look: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59804748/why-do-breakpoints-affect-the-behaviour-of-my-application? Thanks.