# Why do breakpoints affect the behaviour of my application?

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio

I have followed these instructions:

1) Create a default Angular application in Visual Studio 2017: File/New/ASP.NET Core Web Application/Angular.

2) Add the following code to the Counter component (counter.component.ts), which is part of the template:

```
@HostListener('keydown', ['$event'])
onInput(e: any) {
  if (e.which < 48 || e.which > 57) {
      e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

3) Replace: `counter.component.html` with this:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Volume" numericControl />
```

Run the app and navigate to the Counter URL.  Everything works as expected i.e. the input box only allows numbers.  However, I then add a breakpoint to @HostListener and the breakpoint is reached when I press a key inside the input box - nothing will appear in the input box.  Once I remove the breakpoint, then numbers will appear in the input box as expected again.  Why is this?

Comment: Break-points usually don't work too well on annotations; set it to the `if` line.

Comment: @Martin Zeitler, do you mean put the breakpoint on the IF line? That is what I did and it affects the behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

The Angular Zone is timing out on the event listener, and Angular is aborting the listener to protect the performance of the application.

You'll find zones loaded in the `/src/app/polyfills.ts` file, and if you disable the use of zones the event won't abort.

I was trying to find supporting documentation to support my answer, but sadly this area of Angular is poorly documented.

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter (or upvoter at this stage).  This sounds like it could be the answer I should mark.  Is there any documentation explaining how to disable zones so that I can prove it to myself?

Comment: @w0051977 don't recommend that you disable zones to work around this. The best thing to do is use the reactive forms and a custom validator to control what can be entered.

Comment: Thanks.  I agree.  However, you cannot stop a character appearing in an input field using a custom validator.  Or can you?

Comment: @w0051977 I've done it before with reactive forms but don't remember how. You can try listening for changes on a control, and then setting the value and pass false for emitting events. Otherwise it's a mess of events.

Comment: Thanks.  Did you do it in the same way I describe in my other question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59793127/can-customvalidators-be-used-to-prevent-data-entry-into-textboxes/59798053?noredirect=1#comment105745252_59798053

Comment: Could you answer the question in my comment above before I mark the answer? Thanks.